# scatterplot of subset on top of a 2d kdeplot with matching color

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I plot a scatterplot of a **subset of data** on top of a 2D KDEplot with all data when there are many hue/categories?

See the code to reproduce what I would like to avoid: scatterplot with different color than the KDEplot background. I didn't find an "algorithm" way to do this.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import seaborn as sns
# data set generate
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples = 200, n_features = 2, centers = 3, random_state = 2, cluster_std = 1.5)
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['a', 'b'])
df['target'] = y


sns.kdeplot(
    data=df,
    x='a', y='b',
    hue='target',
    fill=True,
    alpha=0.2)


sns.scatterplot(
        data=df,
        x="a", y="b",
        hue="target",
    )

plt.show()

sns.kdeplot(
    data=df,
    x='a', y='b',
    hue='target',
    fill=True,
    alpha=0.2)


sns.scatterplot(
        data=df[df.target==2],
        x="a", y="b",
        hue="target",
    )
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Create a custom palette for the unique targets: 1. `cats = sorted(df.target.unique())`, 2. `palette = dict(zip(cats, sns.cubehelix_palette(n_colors=len(cats))))`, and then pass it to the palette parameter. `palette=palette`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works with categorical palette:

1. provide `hue_order` with all the categorical in correct order regarding the expected legend
2. select only the `handles` and `labels` corresponding to you selected data to build a custom legend.

_

```
import seaborn as sns
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples = 200, n_features = 2, centers = 3, random_state = 2, cluster_std = 1.5)
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['a', 'b'])
df['target'] = y
unique_y = np.unique(df.target)

sns.kdeplot(
    data=df,
    x='a', y='b',
    hue='target',
    hue_order=unique_y,
    fill=True,
    alpha=0.2,
    palette='deep')

sns.scatterplot(
        data=df,
        x="a", y="b",
        hue="target",
        hue_order=unique_y,
        palette='deep'
    )

plt.show()

sns.kdeplot(
    data=df,
    x='a', y='b',
    hue='target',
    hue_order=unique_y,
    fill=True,
    alpha=0.2,
    palette='deep')

select_data = df[df.target==2]
sns.scatterplot(
        data=select_data,
        x="a", y="b",
        hue="target",
        hue_order=unique_y,
        palette='deep',
    )

i_labels = np.unique(select_data)
handles_, labels_ = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
handles_ = [h for i, h in enumerate(handles_) if i in i_labels]
labels_ = [l for i, l in enumerate(labels_) if i in i_labels]

plt.legend(
    handles=handles_,
    labels=labels_,
    bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1),
    title='target'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the [`hue_norm`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

> **hue_norm**  *tuple or `matplotlib.colors.Normalize`*
>
> Either a pair of values that set the normalization range in data units or an object that will map from data units into a [0, 1]
> interval. Usage implies numeric mapping.

```
sns.scatterplot(
        data=df[df.target==2],
        x="a", y="b",
        hue="target",
        hue_norm=(df.target.min(), df.target.max())
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It works well for numerical values or ordinal target through an label encoder. However I did not succeed to make it work for categorical target. I proposed below my answer you work with both and with different palette colors.